# Importing a spreadsheet from our website to our users Google Sheets account

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm trying to figure out a simple way to allow the users of our website to press a button to import a spreadsheet (which is created dynamically in code within the website) into their Google Sheet drive.

Right now I'm currently I've setup a button that allows users to log in to their Google Account with the scope set to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file". However, it's asking our users for way too much personal information for our taste, which we don't need at all.

[image: Google Login Picture]

Is there any other simpler way to do this without accessing personal information? I've noticed that when you log into Google Analytics and export data there it's just a simple Import button and you get your data immediately. That's exactly what I'm be looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify the exact operation you need to carry out? Is it basically to create a file in the users main Drive?

Comment: Yes. Create the file dynamically in code and then add to their drive. I'll edit the post.

Comment: `drive.file` is the recommended scope, there is not much lower than that. It only allows access to the files created by the app, or the files explicitly given permission. This happens on a file by file basis. There is no real personal info unless they give permission to access a sensitive doc. Are you perhaps trying to find a way to not have to go through the verification process?

Comment: You could say that. I uploaded a picture to show what information Google is asking for whenever a user will attempt to get the file (while using drive.file scope). The last permission makes sense for what we're trying to accomplish, but we do not want personal information that Google seems to be giving us by default. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you share the code of the button or a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can try to reproduce the situation on my end? The first one, `Associate you with your personal info....` is necessary for all OAuth2 flows. However, you can in theory choose not to include the `See your personal info...` one but you will need the `See your primary...` one. See the `scope` parameter [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#scope-param) but I'm not sure how you have things set up exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Best and simpliest way is to give them the link to the spreadsheet with copy at the end

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxidxxxxxxxxx/copy
```

Comment: It would be a nice solution. Sadly due to the scale of the project it doesn't quite work out.  Spreadsheet need to be dynamically created in code and then added to the user's Google Sheet.